# I have a question about modifying variables in OOP

Tags: python, oop, variables

I have this file called `mainClass.py`:

```
summed = 3
class myClass:
   def test1(self):
   print(summed)
   summed = 5
```

I can print the `summed` variable, but I can't modify it. Why?

Comment: You need `global summed`, just like in an ordinary function. This has nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: Plesae fix your indentation. What you've shown has nothing in the body of the `test1` function, which is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Barmar I'm surprised this doesn't throw an error, using a variable before it's assigned.

Comment: @MarkRansom yep, throws `UnboundLocalError` when you call `test1`

Comment: @MarkRansom If `print(summed)` is in the function but `summed = 5` is at the class level, there's no error.

Comment: @Martineau That edit may not be right. We need to know how they actually indented `summed = 5`

Comment: @Barmar: I don't think it matters.

Comment: @martineau It does. Your version raises an exception, the OP's actual code might not.

Answer (score 2):

`summed` at the main level is a global variable. If want to access the global variable then add `global summed` to the function.

In the posted function, printing `summed` followed by a local assignment will result in an error:
*UnboundLocalError: local variable 'summed' referenced before assignment* since the variable in the function has become a local variable due to the assignment statement `summed = 5`. For further explaination, refer to the [FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value).

```python
summed = 3'

class myClass:
   def test1(self):
     global summed
     print('  test1:', summed)
     summed = 5 # updates global summed variable

   def test2(self):
     summed = 10 # this is a local summed variable
     print('  test2:', summed)

print("main:", summed)
a = myClass()
a.test1()
print("main:", summed)
a.test2()
print("main:", summed)
```

**Output:**

```
main:  3
  test1: 3
main:  5
  test2: 10
main:  5
```

After calling `test1()` function, `summed` value is changed to `5` but calling `test2()` changes a local `summed` variable not the global variable so value remains 10.

Answer (score 0):

The summed variable you are printing is the global summed which is 3, if you want to print the class summed variable (or modify it) you should added self. to the variable like this:

```
summed = 3
class myClass:
   def test1(self):
       print(self.summed)
   summed = 5
```

Now if you modify summed like this

```
c = myClass()
c.summed = 6
c.test1()
```

it will print 6.
In case you want to change the global summed variable, just add global keyword to it like this:
summed = 3

```
class myClass:
   def test1(self):
       print(self.summed)
   global summed
   summed = 12
```

This will change the value of the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

python thinks it is a local variable and produces `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'summed' referenced before assignment` you should change your code to

```
summed = 3
class myClass:
   def test1(self):
     global summed
     print(summed)
     summed = 5
     
myClass().test1()
print(summed)
```

It would now think summed as a global variable and print

```
3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If a function *assigns* to a variable*, then that variable is assumed to be local, even if there is a global variable of the same name.

If you want the function to use the global variable, you have to use the `global` keyword.

```
def test1(self):
    global summed
    # all references to 'summed' in this function will use the global variable
    ...
```

*This is true even if the assignment is in a branch that doesn't execute -- even in a branch that *can't* execute!

For example:

```
A = 5

def foo():
    if False:
        A = 4
    else:
        print(A)

foo()
```

This code will throw an exception at `print(A)`.